# Failing to update the database through SqlCeConnection on dot net 3.5

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2005

Hey guys
I am using visual studio to develop a windows form application. Csharp is the language being used. I use the following method to update my members records. It doesnot give me an error when called. but when I check the database, the update values doesnt take place. Below is the following code:

```
public static void updatePersonInfo(int number, string password,string firstname, string lastname, string address, string city, string province, string postal, int typeid,bool suspend)
    {
        SqlCeConnection sqlConn = null;
        SqlCeCommand cmdUpdate;
        int susBit = 0;
        if (suspend == true)
        {
            susBit = 1; 
        }

        try
        {
            sqlConn = new SqlCeConnection(databaseString);
            sqlConn.Open();


            cmdUpdate = new SqlCeCommand(@"UPDATE PersonInfo
                                    SET First_Name = @fname, Last_Name =@lname, Address = @address, 
                                    City = @city, Province = @prov, Postal_Code = @post, Type = @type, 
                                    Password = @pass, Suspended = @susp
                                    WHERE Number = @numb", sqlConn);
            cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@numb", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = number;
            cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@fname", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = firstname;
            cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@lname", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = lastname;
            cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@address", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = address;
            cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@city", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = city;
            cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@prov", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = province;
            cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@post", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = postal;
            cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@type", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = typeid;
            cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@pass", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = password;
            cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@susp", SqlDbType.Bit)).Value = susBit;
            cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            if (sqlConn != null)
            {
                sqlConn.Close();
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't spot anything wrong in the method.

Possible reasons that I would check next:

- You are using a `number` value that doesn't correspond to an existing record.
- The method is actually never called.
- You are supplying the same value as before for each field, so that it updates but doesn't change.

Note: A bit field corresponds to a boolean, so you don't have to create a numeric value from the boolean, you can use it directly as a value:

```
cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@susp", SqlDbType.Bit)).Value = suspend;
```

Comment: the method is being called. I cannot understand why it is not updating the database. its the same issue with the delete function.

Answer (score 0):

Six months later, but I just came across this doing another search.

You need to specify a size to your nVarChar data fields.

Using your code, I set all of the `nVarChar` *SqlDbTypes* to `50`....

```
cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@numb", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = number;
cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@fname", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50)).Value = firstname;
cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@lname", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50)).Value = lastname;
cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@address", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50)).Value = address;
cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@city", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50)).Value = city;
cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@prov", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50)).Value = province;
cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@post", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50)).Value = postal;
cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@type", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = typeid;
cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@pass", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50)).Value = password;
cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@susp", SqlDbType.Bit)).Value = susBit;
cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I hope you already resolved this problem.

This note is for everyone else that happens along this way.